# SQL - How to avoid the joining of three queries into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, subquery

I have a SQL script that selects assignments that a student has been assigned. In order to find out if the student completed his assignment, i use  a sub-query. Once the student finishes an assignment he should be able to work on the next one.

I figure I can do this by selected the top 1 assignment that has not been completed ( 0 value). Which I can do with an additional query, of the first query, but then i would need a third query to join that query together. Is there a way i can achieve this selection of the top 1 assignment that has a value of 0, with 2 queries or less?

First Attempt

```
SELECT ag.group_id, 
    ag.title, 
    ac.collection_id, 
    ag.order, 
    ac.NAME, 
    ac.isactive, 
    (SELECT top 1 iscompleted 
        FROM student_completion 
        WHERE fk_collection_id = collection_id 
        AND fk_student_id like '404') 
      AS isCompleted, 
FROM assignments AS ag 
    JOIN assignments_collection AS ac 
    ON ag.fk_collection_id = ac.collection_id 
Order BY group_id

/*
SELECT TOP 1 isCompleted
(SELECT ag.group_id, 
    ag.title, 
    ac.collection_id, 
    ag.order, 
    ac.NAME, 
    ac.isactive, 
    (SELECT top 1 iscompleted 
        FROM   student_completion 
        WHERE  fk_collection_id = collection_id 
            AND fk_student_id like '404') 
    AS isCompleted, 
FROM   assignments AS ag 
    JOIN assignments_collection AS ac 
        ON ag.fk_collection_id = ac.collection_id 
Order BY group_id)
Where isCompleted = 0 

 .........
*/
```

Data

```
+----------+--------------+---------------+-------+----------------------+----------+-------------+
| group_id |    title     | collection_id | order |         name         | isactive | isCompleted |
+----------+--------------+---------------+-------+----------------------+----------+-------------+
|        1 | Assingment_1 |             5 |     0 | Welcome to Linux     |        1 |           0 |
|        2 | Assingment_2 |             6 |     0 | Installation         |        1 |           0 |
|        3 | Assingment_3 |             9 |     1 | Intro to Bash        |        1 |           0 |
|        3 | Assingment_4 |             3 |     1 | Intro to Bash part 2 |        1 |           0 |
+----------+--------------+---------------+-------+----------------------+----------+-------------+
```

Expected Data

```
+----------+--------------+---------------+-------+----------------------+----------+-------------+-----------+
| group_id |    title     | collection_id | order |         name         | isactive | isCompleted | available |
+----------+--------------+---------------+-------+----------------------+----------+-------------+-----------+
|        1 | Assingment_1 |             5 |     0 | Welcome to Linux     |        1 |           0 |         1 |
|        2 | Assingment_2 |             6 |     0 | Installation         |        1 |           0 |         0 |
|        3 | Assingment_3 |             9 |     1 | Intro to Bash        |        1 |           0 |         0 |
|        3 | Assingment_4 |             3 |     1 | Intro to Bash part 2 |        1 |           0 |         0 |
+----------+--------------+---------------+-------+----------------------+----------+-------------+-----------+
```

student_completion

```
+---------------+------------------+-------------+
| FK_studentKey | FK_collectionKey | isCompleted |
+---------------+------------------+-------------+
|           404 |                5 |           1 |
+---------------+------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: What table is your example data from? What's the structure of your other two tables? Do you have example data for them as well? Expected output would also be helpful.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: It looks like you posted the desired output? You need to provide the details of the tables if you want some help. And don't be surprised if we don't give you an answer as this looks a LOT like homework.

Comment: @SeanLange i hope this helps out. Its not homework, im just trying to write a better application.

Comment: Your desired output doesn't seem to match your sample data. And why is isCompleted included in both tables?

Comment: @SeanLange Right, i'm trying to get an additional column called available. That tells the application the student has access to the assignment. I can figure this out by selecting the top row where the isCompleted row is equal to 0. The problem is that requires an additional query, and that additional query can not have that column . So i would have to make a third query to try and join the data, so its finally in the column. Then im calling these query's several times. I dont blame you, its a really hard problem to figure out. I might just have to do this via code instead of sql

Comment: I doubt it, but your sample is quite confusing. Why is IsCompleted in the table of available courses? And what does the student table have to do with this? You are not providing the whole problem, only part of it. The student info is not listed in the output so what happens when there are multiple rows in the completion table? I think you need to step back a little bit and explain the whole situation here. This probably isn't that difficult but the explanation is incomplete which makes this a lot harder than it needs to be.

Comment: In your desired output you have the first course as being available but it is also marked as completed in the data but not the output. And you need something in your Data to indicate an order. You have a column named order but it can't be used to order the rows in that table by itself.

Comment: @SeanLange There is a table student_completion, which stores which assignment the student completed. The student table is not needed. Its the student id needed for the completed assignment. Order doesnt matter at the moment. The two colums that matter are isCompleted and a column i would like added to the select statment called available. I want to get the TOP 1 column where isCompleted is = 0. I want to then set the available column to 1 where the TOP 1 isCompleted column is = 0 . Im sorry if im doing to bad job of explaining.

Comment: Order absolutely matters here. Without order the concept of TOP 1 is ambiguous. I assume you join on collection_id to FK_collectionKey? That is one of my biggest pet peeves in database design. A column should not change names across tables. It adds confusion and ambiguity for no benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is extremely lacking in explanation. I am taking a shot in the dark here. Does this do what you want?

```
select d.*
    , available = sc.isCompleted
from Data d
left join student_completion sc on sc.FK_colletionKey = d.collection_id
```